# How can I test my website on safari with a windows PC

Tags: safari, cross-browser

I currently have a problem with a website on Apple Safari (mobile). there is a horizontal scrollbar an I need to fin out why

Turning on dev tools and choosing an IPhone doesn't show me the problem.

Safari is discontinued on windows, and there's no Linux alternative.

What do you guys do? I prefer a free option.

looked for a bit online for options but didn't find anything satisfying.